# Similarities between microeconomic and macroeconomic failure. And, how microeconomic failures affect the economy at the macro level?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, open-economy-macro, market-failure, economic-failure

I can't make a relation between microeconomic and macroeconomic failures? I know they have differences. However, I want to know the effect of these two economic breakdowns on each other.
I am meaning recessions and inflation for macroeconomy failure. And for micro economy failure, I am meaning by the free rider, externality, market power

Comment: what do you mean by microeconomic and macroeconomic failures? Can you give an example? You mean shocks? Recessions? Deviations from perfect market? You target this with both market failure which has very specific meaning in econ literature and economic failure that is broad term that could mean almost anything.

Comment: Yes, I am meaning recessions and inflation for macroeconomy failure. And for micro economy failure, I am meaning by the free rider, externality, market power